# Profinite topology on free metabelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $M$ be free metabelian group of rank $n$. By work of Coulbois, M is $LERF$ and is not $RZ_2$, that means every finitely generated subgroup of $M$ is closed in the profinite topology of $M$ but the product of two finitely generated subgroups of $M$ may not be closed in the profinite topology of M. My question is the following:

Is there an algorithm to compute the closure of  the product of two finitely generated subgroups of $M$?

Comment: I think this is an open problem